# R: Shift some rows by one column across table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data frame X that looks like this. It has 4 columns and 5 rows.

name  age  gender class 
A            12        M           C1
B           10        F           C2
C           M         C1          N/A
D           F         C2          N/A
E           F         C1          N/A

I would like to shift all data  from col 2 (age) and row 3 onward by one column to right so that gender and classes align leaving the wrongly filled age data as blank . My resulting set should look like:

name  age  gender class 
A           12        M           C1
B           10        F           C2
C           N/A       M           C1
D           N/A       F           C2
E           N/A       F           C1

Please note: this is a situation from a very large dataset with 4 mil records and 52 cols. 
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post code for your best attempt? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry no  code available as yet

Comment: Well... just take into account that you will not always get answers if you don't post code. It depends on willingness of people to solve your problem from a "requirement"... Please take a look to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to figure out how to ask a good question, next time. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
nc  <- ncol(dfr)
dfr[-(1:2), 3:nc] <- dfr[-(1:2), 2:(nc-1)]
dfr[-(1:2), 2] <- NA
```

The negative indices in the rows mean 'everything but rows 1 and 2'.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually trying to get row number of the first occurrence of the issue. In the example here it is row 3. I need to determine this row number to be able to use your solution.

Comment: `which(is.na(dfr[,3]))` will tell you which rows of column 3 are `NA`.

Comment: I have a similar problem which I have tried to work out with your solution, but I am a bit new to R and it is failing. Each row has an unknown number of NAs, and I need to shift all the non-NA values to the end of the row (before filling the NAs with the value from the row above!)

I have currently added a column with the count of NAs, but I also think overwriting non-matching data types may be causing me a problem...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
> df <- data.frame("name" = LETTERS[1:5], 
+            "age" = c(12, 10, "M","F","F"),
+            "gender" = c("M", "F", "C1", "C2", "C1"),
+            "class" = c("C1", "C2", NA,NA,NA))
> df
  name age gender class
1    A  12      M    C1
2    B  10      F    C2
3    C   M     C1  <NA>
4    D   F     C2  <NA>
5    E   F     C1  <NA>

> df[3:nrow(df),3:ncol(df)] <- df[3:nrow(df),2:ncol(df)]
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 3:nrow(df), 3:ncol(df), value = list( :
provided 3 variables to replace 2 variables

> df
   name age gender class
1    A  12      M    C1
2    B  10      F    C2
3    C   M      M    C1
4    D   F      F    C2
5    E   F      F    C1
> df[3:nrow(df),2] <- NA
> df
   name  age gender class
1    A   12      M    C1
2    B   10      F    C2
3    C <NA>      M    C1
4    D <NA>      F    C2
5    E <NA>      F    C1
```